# Unable to find regular file with default shell as bash but works when it's ksh

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ksh

We have script file *FileChecker.sh* where it checks whether file exists or not

**FileChecker.sh content:**

```
#!/bin/ksh
FILE=$1
FILE2=$2
if [[ "$FILE" == "" || "$FILE2" == "" ]] ; then
    echo "[ERROR] if Invalid input to $0 \n"
elif [[ ! -f $FILE||  ! -f $FILE2 ]] ; then
    echo "[ERROR] elif Invalid input to $0 \n"
else
   echo "In Else"
fi
```

We are logged in as user `aaa`. Running the script as follows:

```
[aaa@servername cfg]$ ./FileChecker.sh /tmp/lib/my.properties /tmp/lib/my.ear
```

and we are passing the file names with location as the input to the script and the permissions are `755` on the input files.
we ran the `FileChecker.sh` with user `aaa` and the script executed and it found the file but when we execute the `FileChecker.sh` file with user `www` then the script is unable to locate the input files and prints `[ERROR] elif Invalid input to FileChecker.sh`.

Following are the details about file permissions and the default Shell for both the users. default shell for `aaa` is `/bin/ksh` and for `www` it is `/bin/bash`.

```
[aaa@servername lib]$ cd /tmp/lib
[aaa@servername lib]$ ls -lrt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 aaa aaagroup      175 Apr 16 11:12 my.properties
-rwxr-xr-x 1 aaa aaagroup 14354727 Apr 16 11:12 my.ear


[aaa@servername lib]$ cat /etc/passwd | grep aaa
aaa:x:129822:602:aaa, env.xyz Hostgroup, Id, F, Num:/home/aaa:/bin/ksh

[aaa@servername lib]$ cat /etc/passwd | grep www
www:x:13113:602:www, Hostgroup, Id, F, Num:/home/www:/bin/bash
```

How to I get it working by running as `www` user.

Comment: What are the permissions on the *directory* `/tmp/lib`? perhaps it is not executable for user `www`

Comment: It is `drwx------ 2 aaa aaagroup 4096 Apr  3 09:47 lib`

Comment: That's your problem: user `www` cannot read the directory, so the `-f $FILE` test fails. You need to `chmod 755 /tmp/lib` (or use `setfacl` to specifically give user www extra permissions on the directory if you don't want to open it up to the world)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're observing is is not a result of the users' different login shells.

The issue is that your `www` user does not have execute permission on the containing directory `/tmp/lib` (and so can't traverse it in order to test the file properties within it).

Ex. given

```
$ namei -l /tmp/lib/my.properties 
f: /tmp/lib/my.properties
drwxr-xr-x root        root        /
drwxrwxrwt root        root        tmp
drwxrw-r-- steeldriver steeldriver lib
-rwxr-xr-x steeldriver steeldriver my.properties
```

then

```
$ sudo -u testuser ./FileChecker.sh /tmp/lib/my.properties /tmp/lib/my.ear
[ERROR] elif Invalid input to ./FileChecker.sh \n
```

but

```
$ chmod o+x /tmp/lib
$ sudo -u testuser ./FileChecker.sh /tmp/lib/my.properties /tmp/lib/my.ear
In Else
```